# Deleting list from pardot

Tags: list, automation, pardot

I have many lists in Pardot. Some of them are tied to automation rules. When I try to delete a list, it shows "List is in use by one or more dependencies". Is there a way that I can know which are the dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the particular list and check the usage tab.[image]